# Adding pub_Date to an RSS feed hosted on Wordpress

Tags: customization, rss, facebook

I am trying to use the FaceBook application [RSS Grafitti](http://www.rssgraffiti.com/) to link my RSS feed from my Wordpress installation to a FaceBook Fanpage. It finds the feed OK, but cannot post to the Fan page because there is apparently no pubDate field in the RSS feed.

I am not even sure where to find the file to edit in my WordPress installation. I have WordPress 3.0.1 installed on a shared Linux host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try feeding the app an atom feed instead. (i.e. /feed/atom/ instead of /feed/.) The needed field(s) might be in there.

Else, there are a few hooks to add them via plugins (see the wp-includes/feed-*.php files).

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the underscore as the actual value is pubDate and it (now at Wordpress 3.6) works on `https://example.com/blogname/feed/`

Try `curl http://example.com/blogname/feed/` in terminal/shell/CLI to find out the formatting.